# Alterar sessão do Oracle para aceitar numero com vírgula e do ponto em C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Ao abrir uma conexão com oracle em `C#`, preciso que os `.` e as `,` se comportem conforme a regra `0.000,00` num numero real.  Gostaria de saber como faço para alterar esse formato na sessão aberta no `OracleConnection`

Comment: Como você está montando sua sentença? Pode colocar um exemplo de código?

Comment: A começar pela sentença do título: "vírgula e..."? e...?

Comment: @bfavaretto Deve ser uma pausa dramática.

Comment: nao e q eu rodo o sql em varias maquinas e cada uma esta configurada de uma forma, umas estao com padarao ingles (.) e outras o separador e o padrao portuques(,), ja forcei o programa a ficar em portuques.

Comment: queria saber c tem como alterar o charset da sessao do oracle

Comment: nao esta dando erro de number exption ora-01772

Comment: Estás a usar `OracleParameter`s nos teus `OracleCommand`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme esse artigo no SO original, existem várias respostas que podem elucidar o seu problema: [how-to-format-oraclenumber-generically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244493/how-to-format-oraclenumber-generically)

Segue uma que eu gostei:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,'
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que fique no formato `pt-BR` e isso se reflita nas demais configurações, principalmente nas regionais utilize:

> Windows Form: Aplicação Desktop

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR")
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR")
```

> Web: Forms ou MVC Web Apllication

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR"/>
</system.web>
```

Com essas configurações ele vai configurar sua aplicação com um comportamento regional, sendo muito importante, porque, você não precisa interferir nessas conversões que são feitas automaticamente. Tenho aplicações Web rodando em servidores fora do Brasil e isso é de suma importância.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, bastou alterar a sessão do Oracle